# Vue components hierarchy and passing data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm writing an app in Vue and I have a really hard time understanding the component hierarchy, namely the parent-child relationships and how to pass data around.

I have a view that contains a map which in turn has some navigation controls and options that are overlayed on top of the map. Now, I want these controls to manipulate the map WITHOUT having to nest the buttons inside the actual maps as it will cause severe display issues (for example, clicking on a zoom button falls through the button and also clicks the next element under it).

My app looks like this:

```
Mapview
    Map
    Controls
    Options
        Optionpanel1
        Optionpanel2
        ...
```

Now, a HTML input element in Optionpanel1 needs to control something in the Map, which is not actually it's parent component. Also, some data from Map needs to be passed down to Optionpanel1 so it would know what to control. To make matters worse, something in Options also needs to pass something down to Optionpanel1, so, even though event bus would allow communication upwards, it would not solve that I need to pass data from parents to indirect children and also components that are not it's children.

I can actually pass the required property down the line if I nest the Options inside Map and pass it down with :myProp="prop" and then in Options, declare it in props and bind to Optionpanel1, where it is again declared as a prop. But as I mentioned earlier, nesting elements that I do not want to be nested in a visual sense causes massive issues like mouse click falling through. Do elements even need to be nested inside eachother in order to define parent-child relationship?
I would want components to exchange read-only data without Y being a child of X in the DOM. Also, even if nesting components like this would not cause visual issues, does it not seem very annoying to have to register and bind it in every component along the way?

I don't understand why is it so difficult to simply read something from another component. It's starting to seem that Vue is causing a problem that it's supposed to solve? Am I missing something here or am I looking at this in a completely wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have 2 options to control complex components:

1. Handle the actions in your so-called "smart component" (in terms of React), which is the common ancestor for the controlling and controlled components. It's a pretty good solution for small components, but that's not the case.
2. To separate common logic and data in a Vuex store. I'd recommend you doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it answered none of my questions. Can you explain how a Vuex solves the problem of communicating stuff to other components?

Comment: @Xvs In short, it's like a global variable, which every component can basically read/write from. If you want a long explanation, read the documentation. Vuex seems to be the easiest solution from your problem. But you can also just keep passing data through every child if need be, which avoids Vuex, though is not as maintainable.